# Из строки получить число с точкой?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста, пока мало изучил регулярки, но попытался сделать следующее:
/\d+.+\d/
Нужно проверить, если ли число с точкой в строке, если да, то занести в массив

Comment: Вы случаем не тот человек, который пытается таким образом определить, целое число или нет? А то был тут случай ))

Comment: Знак плюс означает "один или более символов". Т.е. вы неправильно поставили знак плюс.

Answer (score 3):

Извиняюсь конечно, но функция [is_float](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-float.php) принимает **mixed** $var

Если всё же желаете регулярку - `/^\d+\.\d+$/`

```
^ - начало строки
\d - любая цифра
+ - 1 или более
\. - просто точка. Если написать без слеша, то любой символ.
$ - конец строки.
```

Comment: а floatval() еще и возвращает то самое найденное число :)
Забейте на регулярку, только в производительности потеряете

Answer (score 0):

А не проще:

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/isu',$html, $array);
```

Comment: Вы флаги isu от балды поставили? Круглые скобки не нужны т.к. тс только проверяет вхождение. [0-9] лучше заменить на \d, смотрится кошернее. саму функцию нужно заменить на preg_match.

Comment: упс, прочитал невнимательно. Если только на наличие, то разумеется вы правы. Эти флаги я ставлю всегда, независимо от ситуации.

Comment: @Arc ну почитайте мануал по флагам. Флаг "s" далеко не то делает, что ожидалось.